Forward SIPREC to another SBC?
I not not know if this possible, but i need to accept a SIPREC invite from our CORE SBC in Oracle Occas, then forward/Proxy/ReInvite (whatever) our DMZ SBC at a later time.
SBC -> Occas (only send to DMZ when user triggered) -> DMZ-SBC -> Third party.
Original Invite
Handle invite - Ack - return inactive.
@Override
protected void doInvite(SipServletRequest request) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // Handle the INVITE from SBC (Act as UAS for this SIP dialog)
    SipSession incomingSession = request.getSession();
    
    // Respond to the SBC with 200 OK (terminate the dialog as a UAS)
    String sdpResponse = "v=0\r\n" +
                         "o=- 13760799956958020 13760799956958020 IN IP4 1.1.1.1\r\n" +
                         "s=-\r\n" +
                         "c=IN IP4 1.1.1.1\r\n" +
                         "t=0 0\r\n" +
                         "m=audio 49170 RTP/AVP 0\r\n" +
                         "a=sendrecv\r\n";  // Media attributes for SBC
    
    SipServletResponse response = request.createResponse(200);
    response.setContent(sdpResponse, "application/sdp");
    response.send();
}

Rest Endpoint to trigger:
I am trying to send a request to the next sbc with the original SDP.
SipServletRequest originalInvite = RequestService.requests.get(callId);
            String originalContent = RequestService.content.get(callId);
            if (originalInvite == null) {
                return Response.status(Response.Status.NOT_FOUND).entity("Original INVITE not found for Call-ID: " + callId).build();
            }
            

            SipSession applicationSession = originalInvite.getSession();

            SipURI sipURIPrimary = sipFactory.createSipURI(null, ipAddress);
            sipURIPrimary.setTransportParam("tcp");
            sipURIPrimary.setPort(5060);
            Address nextSbc= sipFactory.createAddress(sipURIPrimary);

            SipServletRequest newInvite = sipFactory.createRequest(
                    applicationSession.getApplicationSession(),
                    "INVITE",
                    originalInvite.getSession().getLocalParty(),
                    nextSbc);

            newInvite.setRequestURI(sipURIPrimary);

            newInvite.setHeader("required", "siprec");

            newInvite.setContent(originalContent, originalInvite.getContentType());
            newInvite.send();

            return Response.ok("Request Sent").build();

Response:
SIP/2.0 400 Bad Request - SRC feature tag missing in contact header
Error : SIP/2.0 400 Bad Request - SRC feature tag missing in contact header
Content-Length: 0
CSeq: 1 INVITE
Call-ID: jfkldsjflkdsfjdlsfkjsdlf
From: <sip:<OCCAS>:5070;transport=tcp>;tag=dsdasas
To: <sip:<DMZ>:5060;transport=tcp>;tag=ffffffff
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP <OCCAS>:5070;wlsscid=-dsdsadsadasd;branch=dsdsadsadsa

As i understand it, i cannot modify the Contact header at all.
Original Sample invite
INVITE sip:<phoneNumber>@<OCCAS>:5070 SIP/2.0
Via: SIP/2.0/TCP 1.1.1.1:5060;branch=56456464456
From: sip:SBC@1.1.1.1;tag=45645464546
To: <sip:<OCCAS>:5070;transport=tcp>
Call-ID: dshdkhsadkashdj@<OCCAS>
CSeq: 123456 INVITE
Contact: <sip:SBC@1.1.1.1:5060;transport=tcp>;+sip.src
Max-Forwards: 70
Require: siprec
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=unique-boundary-1
Content-Length: 3081
MIME-Version: 1.0

*** SDP ***


